# JSON.simple - How to correctly access nested JSON objects

Tags: java, json, parsing, simplejson

Example of my json file is

```
{
  "collection": [
    {
      "trophy-name": {
        "text": "swimming",
        "text2": "fast swimming"
      },
      "length": "50m",
      "pool": "outside",
      "weather": "20"
    }
  ]
}
```

Right now I am able to get values from lenght, pool and weather. But I am stuck on how to access the <strike>nested array</strike> nested object `trophy-name`.

My code is:

```
public class main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException
    {         

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("..."));   // json path
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;           
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("collection"); 
 
        for (Object number : array ) 
        {
            JSONObject testObj = (JSONObject) number;   

            String pool = (String)testObj.get("pool");

            System.out.println(testObj.get("length"));
            System.out.println(pool);
            System.out.println(testObj.get("weather"));         
        }           
    }   
}
```

This is my first time experimenting with json files so I am trying to play around with it so the code is not great.

I probably have to create new object like

```
JSONObject trophyObj = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("trophy-name");
```

And then from there I should be able to get the text with this?

```
String troph = (String) trophyObj.get("text");
```

Even if I that is correct I am not sure how to implement it into the loop or if there is better way to do the loop?
Dont mind redoing the code differently and any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right, simply extract the `JSONObject` within the loop and then get the required fields.

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException
    {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("..."));   // json path
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("collection");

        for (Object number : array )
        {
            JSONObject testObj = (JSONObject) number;

            String pool = (String)testObj.get("pool");
            System.out.println(testObj.get("length"));
            System.out.println(pool);
            System.out.println(testObj.get("weather"));

            JSONObject trophyObj = (JSONObject) testObj.get("trophy-name");
            System.out.println((String)trophyObj.get("text"));
            System.out.println((String)trophyObj.get("text2"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Wasnt sure if I was going correctly about it